# Jquery change HTML codes to pure text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my html & jquery scripts

```
<textarea id="id"></textarea>
<div class="messages"></div>
```

When I type something in the `textarea` and press enter, it will run the below script

```
var x = $("textarea#id").val();
$("div.messages").append("<span class='zz'>"+x+"</span>");
```

It successfully works.
But when I type html codes in `textarea` it shows only the html element which typed in `textarea`
ie, When i typed `<b>HTML</b>` it shows **HTML** ,
But I need `<b>HTML</b>`..
I know `.text()` in place of `.html()` .
 But I think , it is not applicable in my code.
Because, the `<span class="zz">` should be a html element.

Comment: try like this "<span class='zz'><xmp>"+x+"</xmp?</span>"

Comment: @VinodLouis If User typed `</xmp><b>adadasd</b>`. it will do not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :-

```
function escape(text) {
    return text
        .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
        .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
        .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
        .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
        .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}

var x = $("textarea#id").val();
$("div.messages").append("<span class='zz'>"+escape(x)+"</span>");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6912r2f5/)

Answer (score 0):

Xmp tag escapes it

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hF985/18/)

```
$("#div1").html("<span><xmp>" + $("#id").val() + "</xmp></span>");
```

Comment: Yeah i agree in that case accepted answer is the elegant one

Answer (score 0):

Can also try putting value inside pre tag so it do not get interpreted as HTML:

```
$('div.messages').html('<span class="zz"><pre>' + $("#id").val() + '</pre></span>');
```

Stuff inside a pre tag cannot be styled however.

Comment: but if user typed `</pre><b>adadasd</b>`

Answer (score 0):

Why is every one doing it so complicated?

```
var x = $("textarea#id").val();
$("<span class='zz'></span>").text(x).appendTo($("div.messages"));
```

Comment: I think it is a better one,, Let me check